# Can function names be configured in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write some javascript to run both client and server side.  I'd like to dynamically rename functions (to aid debugging etc).
I have the following code:

```
function genericFunction() {}
Object.defineProperty(genericFunction, 'name', {writable: true});
genericFunction.name = 'specificFunction';
console.log(genericFunction.name);
```

In chrome (v43) this outputs "specificFunction" as expected.  However, in node.js (v0.10), I get:

> TypeError: Cannot redefine property: name

I've done a little debugging and this seems to be down to the different between the output of

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(function () {}, 'name').configurable);
```

On chrome it's true, but node.js outputs false.

My (very limited) understanding of [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-setfunctionname) is that for function names, configurable should always be true.
Have I missed something in reading the spec? Does node.js use a different spec which says names shouldn't be configurable? Or have I stubbled across a genuine bug?

Comment: Node v0.10 does not claim to be fully compatible with ES6 (in fact, it has rather limited ES6 support). See http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#function_name_property_isn't_writable,_is_configurable

Comment: @jfriend00 - you misunderstand the spec.

Comment: @jfriend00 writable is false by default, but configurable is true.  Therefore my line `Object.defineProperty(genericFunction, 'name', {writable: true});` changes writable to be true from there on.  (Atleast in places that follow the spec)

Comment: @jfriend00 - there's a difference between `writable` vs `configurable`

Comment: @lucas - yeah, but that means by default, you cannot set the .name property unless you first change writable to true.

Comment: because 600 characters is not long enough to explain the ES2015 spec to you

Comment: @jfriend00 - this is not your question, and no mud has been slung. Here's some reading material - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty and https://bocoup.com/weblog/whats-in-a-function-name/

Answer (score 3):

The `.name` property on Function objects cannot be changed in node v.0.12.2 because the name property on Function objects defaults to `writable: false` and `configurable: false` so there's no way to make it writable.

This is not in agreement with ES6.  Since the current implementation of Chrome is in agreement with ES6 in this regard, we can assume that node is just behind in V8 engine version and some future version will fix this.  Note: The `--harmony` flag with node does not change this behavior either.

---

Here's the technical difference between node v.0.12.2 and Chrome 44.0.2403.130 m.

In node v.0.12.2, if you do this:

```
function f() {}
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(f, "name"));
```

It outputs:

```
{value: 'f', writable: false, enumerable: false, configurable: false}
```

As you can see, you cannot write to the `.name` property and you cannot reconfigure it to be writable.

---

In Chrome 44.0.2403.130 m, you get this:

```
{"value":"f","writable":false,"enumerable":false,"configurable":true }
```

You cannot write to it by default, but because it is configurable, you could change it to writable and then change the name property after that.

---

This is presumably because Chrome is running a more recent version of the V8 engine.  Per the [ES6 spec description](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-setfunctionname), the Chrome configuration looks like the proper default.

---

If you run this code in the latest Chrome, you can see that it works:

```js
function f() {}
var alias = f;

log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(f, "name"));

// this name change will not work because writable === false
log(alias.name);
f.name = "foo";
log(alias.name);

// change writable to true
Object.defineProperty(f, "name", {writable: true});
log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(f, "name"));

// this name change will work
f.name = "foo";
log(alias.name);

// utility function to put output into main window for snippet
function log(args) {
    var str = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arguments[i] === "object") {
            str += JSON.stringify(arguments[i]);
        } else {
            str += arguments[i];
        }
    }
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = str;
    var target = log.id ? document.getElementById(log.id) : document.body;
    target.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: My question already pointed out that configurable is true in Chrome, but false in node.

Comment: @lucas - And, I explained that the ES6 spec is consistent with the latest Chrome implementation and node is just behind the times.  What more answer is there than that?  You cannot configure function names in node right now because of this configurability issue.

Comment: Your answer doesn't tell me anything about node that wasn't already in my question.  
You've gone into lots of detail about the Chrome implementation, but I already know that works.

Comment: @lucas - The answer to the question in your title is "No, you cannot set the `.name` property on Function objects in the current version of node".  My answer says that exactly and the rest is an explanation for why this is true which I thought was useful to fully understand (at least it was useful to me).  What else about this issue are you looking to know?

Comment: As of Node 14, the `Object.defineProperty(func, "name", {value: "MyNewFuncName"});` works. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/D5ja8fg.png

Answer (score 0):

While previously not specified at all, the [`.name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) of functions was a non-standard feature in many engines, which made the property to be non-writable and non-configurable though.

With the 6th Edition of ECMAScript this has changed, and `.name` is now an officially specced property of function instances. However, many engines have not yet adopted this change.

That it works in your Chrome browser suggests that one of the newer versions of V8 supports this. Consider updating your node.js, or switch to io.js.

---

> Can function names be configured in node.js?

As you have established, no (or at least, not currently).

> My (very limited) understanding of the spec is that for function names, configurable should always be true.

Yes.

> Have I missed something in reading the spec?

No.

> Does node.js use a different spec which says names shouldn't be configurable?

No.

> Or have I stubbled across a genuine bug?

I'd call it a "missing feature", not a bug. Node doesn't claim to support ES6 yet, so while they do plan to do in the future it's not really a bug currently.